# TypeScript: Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type when accessing object prop with bracket notation

Tags: typescript

I have this for loop where I'm accessing each credential's `name` and `id`, like this:

```
    for (const cred of provider.credentials || []) {
        const credId = cred.id
        const credName = cred.name
        const credValue = state[credName]
    }
```

However, I'm getting the error mentioned in the title when defining `credValue`

I know this is happening because `credName` might be `null`. I'm using the Non-null assertion operator to try to deal with this, but I haven't been able to do it successfully.

And to be clear, the state object always looks like something like this:

```
state: {
   cred1: 'value'
   cred2: 'value'
}
```

Comment: Can `credName` *actually* be null or undefined during runtime? If yes, then handle that case and return early since its an expected outcome, if not then the type of `provider.credentials` needs to be adjusted and it would be useful if you could share it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `ts` compiler that `credName` is a key of `state`.

Try this one:

```
var state = {
   cred1: 'value1',
   cred2: 'value2'
}

type stateKeyType = keyof typeof state;

    for (const cred of provider.credentials || []) {
        const credId = cred.id
        const credName = cred.name as stateKeyType
        const credValue = state[credName]
    }
```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/G4QwTgBADmD2wEsAmBTSBeCBvAxmFqAdgC4IgA2AzgFwDaWy1AjADQSEgC2K1A5HgSa8AvgF1hAbgBQoSJWIhiKCJixSIGgUibUIvUOQCuKIS3Wb8SAEy79FY1d5ThUqcQCeUZfMUoA0ijuACqeypgA1oGwAGYQHl4xED5K0uYa0bCQABQ4sITyEFoQiTDwyGgAdFooJGRUEAA%20DRC0ogCU2Gka3bn5xIWWAJJIKgMEFchd3YV5BVoAclxhY0gVHNwQIJRJCkoBwaFTPbP9WgBq9svJKLQLS6Ku09O9lLDkKBXksADmOZYXRhQbWk02EQA)